# Rails production server not showing changes to views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, production-environment

I'm hosting a Rails 4 app on an ec2 instance and using Nginx, I added a view to a controller and was getting an error trying to navigate to the page through my browser till I reloaded nginx.conf. Once it came up I made some changes to the view but those weren't showing either till I reloaded nginx.conf again.

Obviously I don't want to reload nginx.conf every time I need to change a view. Is there something I'm missing to make this easier on myself?

Here is my nginx.conf file.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  app-on-rails;
    passenger_enabled on;
    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    root   /home/usr/www/app-on-rails/welcome;
    index index.html.erb;
}
```

My environments/production.rb file

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.eager_load = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.serve_static_files = false
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.compile = true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your nginx config appears to be using passenger. By default, in production mode all file content is parsed once, and cached in memory - so changes will not be immediately noticeable. To force a refresh, you need to at a minimum restart passenger. This can be done by simply touching the tmp/restart.txt file in your application root directory.

Comment: Does "By default" imply that there's a way to disable or change this behavior temprarily?

Comment: @WhyAyala Yes, you can set `config.action_view.cache_template_loading = false` to do this.  However, due to the performance impact, I strongly recommend against this approach.  If you change or add files, simply touch the restart file.  Requests against the server will not be dropped while passenger restarts.

Comment: I'm trying to set up redmine which is built on top of rails in my local vagrant for customization. The app runs in development mode but still it doesn't pick any model or controller change. I had to restart nginx every time to see the changes. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

In your `environments/production.rb` file, you may change the following line

```rb
config.cache_classes = false
```

This configuration determines, the ruby classes will not be cached. So your changes in code will reflect on refreshing the browser.
As the classes are not cached, performance will be somewhat decreased. So, after your development, this below might be set to `true`.